# Find when button is clicked in iFrame from Parent level

Tags: button, iframe, disqus, click

Is it possible to tell from the parent window when a button is clicked in an iframe without adding any code to the iframe page? Basically we are integrating Badgeville and Disqus into our site and we want to award users points on Badgeville when they comment on a post using Disqus, so we do not have access to the disqus page code we are including. Not quite sure how to tackle this.

EDIT

Turns out Disqus has code to handle this issue. This code must be included in the main file before the main disqus code is included.

```
    <script>
    function disqus_config() {
        this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function() { alert("New Comment"); }];
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

without adding any code that's not possible. because of restrictions added in IFRAME.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using the callback is that it's difficult to figure out who made the comment. You might consider a different approach and use the Disqus API to poll for the latest comments on your site to award those points.

You can poll the 'forums/listPosts' or 'posts/List' endpoints on a schedule and match up the user email addresses so you know who to give the points to. The documentation can be found here: http://disqus.com/api/docs/

Some examples (mostly in PHP) can be found here: https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes